# Replace HTMLElement with XML Element

Tags: javascript, ajax

So, I have a HTML page with differents div element and I have some links that load a xml document

The XML file looks like that :

```
<boxes>
 <div class="grid_4 box" id="siteBox">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  <ul class="listItem">
   ...
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="grid_4 box" id="emplBox">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
  <ul class="listItem">
  ...
  </ul>
 </div>
</boxes>
```

I want all the div contained in my HTML page to be replace by their equivalent (same id) from the XML file

Here is the beginning of my javascript file.

```
function ajaxLink() {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

   var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;

   for(var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.childElementCount; ++i) {
    c = xmlDoc.children[i]; //Element
    d = document.getElementById(c.getAttribute("id")); //HTMLDivElement

   }
  }
 }

 xmlhttp.open("GET", "file.xml", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Could you help me with that, please ?

Thank you

Thomas

Comment: Off-topic: FWIW, it's "replace with", not "replace by". (English appears not to be your native language, but your English is clearly excellent, so I figured you wouldn't mind the info.)

Answer (score 0):

`var newNode = document.createElement('div');

// assign ID, CLASS and innerHTML from c to newNode //

d.parentNode.replaceChild(newNode,d);`

Comment: Thank you, but how can I assign 'innerHTML' from c to newNode ? 'c' is a XML Element and it doesn't have a 'innerHTML' property.

Comment: It has children. I didn't mean literally `innerHTML`, but to hook the contents of the XML node (nodeValue?) to the innerHTML of the new DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested. I think I follow what you are trying to do. In your loop after getting back the response update the innerHTML of the document node with the innerXML of the xml node. Since I don't know of an easy way to get just the innerXml in Firefox and Chrome.

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
for(var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.childElementCount; ++i) {
    c = xmlDoc.children[i]; //Element
    d = document.getElementById(c.getAttribute("id")); //HTMLDivElement
    if (d) { 
        var xml = getXml(c);
        tmp.innerHTML = xml;
        d.innerHTML = tmp.firstChild.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

This is here since IE has a different method of serializing XML. I'm not sure that `outerXML` is what you want, might be `xml` or `outerXml`.

```
function getXml(node) {
    if (window.XMLSerializer) {
        return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(node);
    }

    if (node.outerXML) {
        return node.outerXML;
    }

    return '';
}
```